# .Net Core 3.0 Npgsql Migration Issue

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a .Net Core 3.0 Api using NetTopologySuite, it perfectly works on an SqlServer database but i needed to change to Postgresql, well of course i changed my Startup.cs for a Postgresql configuration (Added the NetTopologySuite) and installed the Postgis  extension on my Postgresql database, the problem is when i want to migrate it throws an **System.InvalidOperationException** exception, i even tried to generate the sql script to manually do it.
I didn't use `HasComment` in my entity configurations.

The exception:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.0.0 initialized 'AppDbContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options: using NetTopologySuite
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.GetColumnType(String schema, String table, String name, ColumnOperation operation, IModel model)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Migrations.NpgsqlMigrationsSqlGenerator.ColumnDefinition(String schema, String table, String name, ColumnOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.ColumnDefinition(AddColumnOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.CreateTableColumns(CreateTableOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Migrations.NpgsqlMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateTableOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder, Boolean terminate)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.<>c.<.cctor>b__71_11(MigrationsSqlGenerator g, MigrationOperation o, IModel m, MigrationCommandListBuilder b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Migrations.NpgsqlMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateScript(String fromMigration, String toMigration, Boolean idempotent)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.ScriptMigration(String fromMigration, String toMigration, Boolean idempotent, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScriptMigrationImpl(String fromMigration, String toMigration, Boolean idempotent, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScriptMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Bogus" Version="28.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NetTopologySuite" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Even trying to add a migration gives me this exception (works perfectly fine on SqlServer)

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.0.0 initialized 'AppDbContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options: using NetTopologySuite 
System.InvalidOperationException: No mapping to a relational type can be found for property 'LocalizerApp.Models.ApplicationUser.TwoFactorEnabled' with the CLR type 'bool'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSourceExtensions.GetMapping(IRelationalTypeMappingSource typeMappingSource, IProperty property)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(IProperty source, IProperty target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(TableMapping source, TableMapping target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IModel source, IModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
No mapping to a relational type can be found for property 'LocalizerApp.Models.ApplicationUser.TwoFactorEnabled' with the CLR type 'bool'.
```

Comment: Any chance you can submit a small code sample that shows how to trigger this? If you're getting a null reference exception that definitely means there's a bug somewhere, and it would be good to find and fix it.

Comment: Sure, i will be posting a sample soon.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, here is the [migration file](https://pastebin.com/9sj6BmQj) that causes these exceptions. I'd be happy to share more if you need it. [startup.cs](https://pastebin.com/SpZz6Qhk)

Comment: I should add that if i generate the migration with postgres as the development db, everything works correctly with both databases.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to run migrations that were generated for SQL Server on PostgreSQL; this can work, but typically requires at least some work. [See this doc page for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

Comment: Aside from that, it's difficult to see from the big migrations file you posted exactly what is wrong. What is needed in this case is a minimal, runnable sample - it would require a bit more work from you, so that the error can be reproduced cleanly etc. You can open an issue on the repo as well.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  The error I have at the start is similar `Entity Framework Core 3.0.0 initialized 'AppDbContext' ... Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` but deviates afterwards and I'm trying to figure out why AppDbContext is not an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for anyone having a similar problem i solved mine by having two migration sets for each database instead of combining them into a one migration set. [More in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#two-migration-sets)